# How to find and replace string in MYSQL Database for a particular string only

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, sql-update, where-clause

I want to replace a particular string in mysql database, i am using this query :

UPDATE `users` SET `name`=replace(name,'raj','rajesh')

however what this query does is where it find raj it will replaces by rajesh for e.g if there is a string raju in databse after running this query raju becomes rajeshu which i dont want. i want a query which matches the replace string exactly means after running a query only 'raj' should get replaced with 'rajesh' and 'raju' should remain as is.. can someone please help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query works for me:

```
UPDATE users 
SET name = replace(name,'raj','rajesh')
WHERE name = 'raj'
```

Comment: If name like this `raj kumar rajan'?

Answer (score 2):

Try below query to replace `raj` with `rajesh`

```
update users set name=replace(name,' raj ',' rajesh ');
```

OR

```
 update users set name=replace(name,'raj ','rajesh ') where name like '% raj %';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this it will definitely work for you.

```
update users 
set name=replace(LOWER(name),'raj','rajesh') 
where 
name like 'raj %' 
OR 
name like '% raj %'
OR
name = 'raj'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE users 
SET name = 'rajesh' 
WHERE name = 'raj';
```